# Drawing multiple lines in a row using table environment

Tags: tables, tabularx

[image]

I want to draw a table in latex but unable to draw it exactly as shown in Fig. Kindly help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please show us what you try so far and with which line(s) you have problem. many people consider vertical lines not aesthetic and use only necessary horizontal rules from `booktabs` packages.

Comment: Use `\multicolumn`. Standard and simple. :)

Answer (score 5):

As you did not post your MWE so by looking at your figure I have made my own MWE, here is the output of my MWE.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[left=.45in,right=.45in,top=.6in,bottom=.6in,headheight=14.5pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,multirow,textcomp}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}



\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Tech&\multicolumn{4}{c}{Single hom}& \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Excepted Case}\\ \cline{2-8}
   &T. Cost& PAR & \% & / & \raisebox{-0.8ex}{\textacutedbl}  & \raisebox{-0.8ex}{\textacutedbl}  & /\\ \cline{2-8}
   &&&&&&&\\ 
   &&&&&&&\\ 
   &&&&&&&\\ 
   &&&&&&&\\ 
   &&&&&&&\\ 
   &&&&&&&\\        
   &&&&&&&\\ \hline


\end{tabular}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd add `\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}`...

Comment: BTW, congrats on passing the 1k reputation mark on this site!

Comment: Thank you very much Biki Teron you have solved it for me and thanks to CarLaTex as well.

Comment: One more thing I would like to ask you is about to close cell of Tech if I want a line after Tech but the 2nd line i.e., not just after the Tech. How Can I do that??

Comment: Change to `\cline{1-8}` in the second command of `\cline{2-8}`@Shane

Comment: If this is your answer then please click on green tick to accept the answer@Shane